# Trying to run quickstart. Error no image ID

Tags: docker, plaid

Followed instructions and installed Docker for the first time.  Then I input everything in terminal as stated.  Error on make up language=node

cannot write /var/folders/fw/44x2zkk9337ddrtbq5cp5w940000gn/T/tmph4o_dkt6 because server did not provide an image ID
ERROR: Service 'frontend' failed to build : Build failed
make: *** [up] Error 1
zsh: command not found: #

Comment: Noone can reproduce this from what information you have given "Then I input everything in terminal as stated. Error on make up language=node". You need to provide those instructions, with a Dockerfile and even a compose file to help resolve your issues.

That said, very few containers come with `zsh` installed. Either install it, or use the supplied `sh` or `bash`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Docker issue - See this thread [here:](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/2971)

```
docker buildx install
```

The above command seemed to work for these folks.